# Error in tree$edge.length : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

Why is this error? Can someone help? :)

It seems that it has problem with `picante` package.

```
library(ape)
library(picante)
library(vegan)
library(permute)
library(lattice)
library(nlme)
#install.packages("e1071")
install.packages("picante")

otu_table<-read.table("Galaxy32.csv",sep=',',row.names=1,header=T)
otu_tablet<-t( otu_table)
otu_tree<-read.tree("G32-Galaxy50-[FastTree.nwk].nwk")

prune_tree <- prune.sample( otu_tablet,otu_tree)
match.comm <- match.phylo.comm(prune_tree,otu_tablet) 
comm <- match.comm$comm
phy <- match.comm$phy
otu_phydist <- cophenetic(phy)
print(str(comm))
phylo_diversity <- pd(phy,comm) #Wrong at this step
write.table(phylo_diversity, file="PD.txt", sep="\t", col.names=FALSE, row.names=TRUE)
```

Debug messages and my variables:

```
> phylo_diversity <- pd(phy,comm)
Error in tree$edge.length : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

> print(str(phy))
List of 5
 $ edge       : int [1:12599, 1:2] 6302 6303 6304 6305 6305 6304 6306 6307 6308 6308 ...
 $ edge.length: num [1:12599] 0.026 0.0275 0.0147 0.0465 0.0896 ...
 $ Nnode      : int 6299
 $ node.label : chr [1:6299] "" "0.938" "0.933" "0.087" ...
 $ tip.label  : chr [1:6301] "OTU_4466" "OTU_5383" "OTU_3093" "OTU_5532" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
 - attr(*, "order")= chr "cladewise"
NULL

> print(str(comm))
 int [1:70, 1:6301] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:70] "D151_2" "D148b_G51" "D152b_G51" "D148a_G21" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:6301] "OTU_4466" "OTU_5383" "OTU_3093" "OTU_5532" ...
NULL

> class(phy)
[1] "phylo"

> print(otu_table) #only paste first few lines of results
         D151_2 D148b_G51 D152b_G51 D148a_G21 D149b_G21 D150a_G21 D151a_G52 D151a_G21 D149_2 D152b_C51 D149b_C51 D150_2
OTU_2189      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0      0         0         0      0
OTU_2008      0         0         0         0         2         0         0         0      0         0         0      0

> print(comm) #only paste first few lines of results
          OTU_4466 OTU_5383 OTU_3093 OTU_5532 OTU_3342 OTU_3453 OTU_1127 OTU_927 OTU_4960 OTU_1147 OTU_3809 OTU_5796
          OTU_5710 OTU_2491 OTU_3018 OTU_3067 OTU_2505 OTU_4329 OTU_3298 OTU_1270 OTU_1086 OTU_3913 OTU_2223 OTU_668
```

I tried re-installing packages, but i didn't work. The outputs of debug seem to be correct.

PS: The debug messages only containes first few lines of results.